# Simplify filtering between 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following working method.
It creates an array of items (which I then use to populate a select dropdown) that haven't otherwise been previously used throughout the rest of the form array. I'm just wondering if there is a shorter more elegant way of doing all this?

```
uniqueChoiceLocaleItems(currentValue) {

        // Create an array of all the ids already taken. ie. ["en", "fr", "es"];
        var idsTaken = [];
        this.myForm['controls'].languages['controls'].forEach((x, index) => {
            if ((x['controls'].id.value != currentValue)) {
                idsTaken.push(x['controls'].id.value);
            }
        });

        // Loop through our main master 'this.locales' array which has ALL the locales in the world and filter out all the ids from the 'idsTaken' array
        var uniqueItems = [];
        this.locales.forEach((x, index) => {
            if (idsTaken.indexOf(x.code) !== -1) {
            } else {
                uniqueItems.push(x);
            }
        });
       
        return uniqueItems;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you want to do. Could you give a jsfiddle or a snippet with an example for using your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple and modified version.

```
var idsTaken = this.myForm["controls"].languages["controls"].filter(
  (x) => x["controls"].id.value != currentValue
).map((x) => x["controls"].id.value);

var uniqueItems = this.locales.filter((x) => idsTaken.indexOf(x.code) === -1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very helpful. Would there be a benefit between your last line and this one: this.locales.filter(item => !idsTaken.includes(item.code)); ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Set` and its constructor callback to create it. Then delete `currentValue` from that set (it doesn't matter whether it was actually in it or not). Finally use `filter`:

```
uniqueChoiceLocaleItems(currentValue) {
    var idsTaken = new Set(
        this.myForm.controls.languages.controls.map(x => x.controls.id.value)
    );
    idsTaken.delete(currentValue);
    return this.locales.filter(x => !idsTaken.has(x.code));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. First time I've seen Set, whats that?

Comment: It is what is says: a set (unique items only) of anything you want. Documentation on mdn: [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). It allows for quick member-check with the `has` method, which has a better time complexity than `includes` on an array (or `indexOf`)